# Trying to figure out when destructors get called

Tags: c++, memory-management

Below I have a class that keeps a reference count and a class that encapsulates a pointer to another object.

When class `Ptr` no longer has any objects attached to it, I want to deallocate. This entails deleting the object and the reference count. It is signaled when the value of `ptrcnt` hits zero.

My `Ptr_count` class has a destructor which does its part of the deallocation. I know that this destructor will get called when the destructor for `Ptr` gets called, and it will free up the memory accordingly. However, I'm not so sure it gets called when the assignment operator of `Ptr` gets called and the code `if(--refptr == 0) { delete p; }` gets executed.

There is a piece of code commented out in `Ptr_count`. If I use this instead of the destructor, the deallocation will occur any time the value of `refptr` goes to zero.

My question is, is there a way for the destructor to be called during the assignment operation in `Ptr` or would I need to use the code in `Ptr_count` that is commented out in order to get proper memory deallocation?

Obviously the destructor will be called when I exit the program and the memory will be freed one way or the other but while the program is running, I think that in that instance, the reference pointer can keep decrementing even after it hits zero and that memory will still be around.

```
class Ptr_count {
public:
    Ptr_count() : ptrcnt(new size_t(1)) { }
    ~Ptr_count()
    {
        if(ptrcnt && *ptrcnt <= 0)
            delete ptrcnt;
    }
    size_t operator++() const
    {
        ++(*ptrcnt);
        return *ptrcnt;
    }
    size_t operator--() const
    {
        --(*ptrcnt);
        /*
        if(*ptrcnt == 0) {
            delete ptrcnt;
            return 0;
        }
        */
        if(ptrcnt)
            return *ptrcnt;
        else
            return 0;

    }
    operator bool() const
    {
        return ptrcnt;
    }
    size_t operator*() const
    {
        return *ptrcnt;
    }
private:
    size_t* ptrcnt;
};
```

---

```
template <class T> class Ptr {
public:
    Ptr() : p(0) {}
    Ptr(T* t) : p(t) {}
    Ptr(const Ptr& h) : p(h.p), refptr(h.refptr) { ++refptr; }

    Ptr& operator=(const Ptr& rhs)
    {
        ++(rhs.refptr);
        if(--refptr == 0) {
            delete p;
        }
        refptr = rhs.refptr;
        p = rhs.p;
        return *this;
    }

    ~Ptr()
    {
        if(--refptr == 0) {
            delete p;
        }
    }

    operator bool() const { return p; }

private:
    T* p;
    Ptr_count refptr;
};
```

EDIT::

Alternatively, if class `Ptr_count` had it's own assignment operator, would this be a work around to the problem? If I added the below code to `Ptr_count`, it seems like I may be able to free the memory when the reference count reaches 0 during assignment.

```
void operator=(const Ptr_count& rhs)
{
    if(ptrcnt == 0)
        delete ptrcnt;
    ptrcnt = rhs.ptrcnt;
}
```

Comment: You should be using `std::shared_ptr` (or lacking `c++11` support) `boost::shared_ptr`.  All these details have been worked out.

Comment: Why do you have a *pointer* to your reference count in `Ptr_count`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if this is for self-teaching only go on. Else stop what you are doing and start using [`std::shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) / [`std::unique_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/) / [`std::weak_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/weak_ptr/) or if you can't use C++11 [`std::auto_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/auto_ptr/).

Now to your code:

**1)** It would be safer and much more natural to increment your reference count in the copy constructor `Ptr_count` instead of the copy constructor of `Ptr`, since the purpose of `Ptr_count` class is to *manage* the reference count.

You can remove `Ptr`'s copy constructor entirely after doing so.

**2)** There is an unnecessary check in the assignment operator of `Ptr`:

```
// Counter *must* be greater than 0 here, else p is 0 anyways.
Ptr& Ptr::operator=(const Ptr& rhs)
{
    ++(rhs.refptr);      // Increment your counter to 2 or above.
    if(--refptr == 0) {  // Decrement your counter to 1 or above.
        delete p;        // Never get here.
    }
    refptr = rhs.refptr;
    p = rhs.p;
    return *this;
}
```

**3)** Your biggest problem is that you are overwriting `refptr` and `p` in the assignment operator.

```
Ptr& operator=(Ptr const& rhs)
{
    Ptr temp(rhs);
    std::swap(refptr, temp.refptr);
    std::swap(p, temp.p);
    return *this;
}
```

should fix that.

**4)** Your decrement operator of `Ptr_count` is somewhat broken.

```
size_t Ptr_count::operator--() const
{
    --(*ptrcnt); // Access address stored in ptrcnt.
    if(ptrcnt)   // Test if address is valid.
        return *ptrcnt;
    else
        return 0;

}
```

If `ptrcnt` was 0 when calling this method you get an access violation because of `--(*ptrcnt)`. Anyway, this should not be necessary, simply remove it:

```
size_t Ptr_count::operator--() const
{
    return --(*ptrcnt);
}
```

**tl;dr**
Because code says more than 1000 words, the complete code:

```
class Ptr_count {
public:
    Ptr_count() : ptrcnt(new size_t(1)) { }
    Ptr_count(Ptr_count const& rhs) : ptrcnt(rhs.ptrcnt) { ++(*this); }
    ~Ptr_count()
    {
        if(ptrcnt && *ptrcnt <= 0)
            delete ptrcnt;
    }
    size_t operator++()
    {
        return ++(*ptrcnt);
    }
    size_t operator--()
    {
        return --(*ptrcnt);

    }
    operator bool() const
    {
        return ptrcnt;
    }
    size_t operator*() const
    {
        return *ptrcnt;
    }
private:
    size_t* ptrcnt;
};

template <class T> class Ptr {
public:
    Ptr() : p(0) {}
    Ptr(T* t) : p(t) {}

    Ptr& operator=(Ptr const& rhs)
    {
        Ptr temp(rhs);
        std::swap(refptr, temp.refptr);
        std::swap(p, temp.p);
        return *this;
    }

    ~Ptr()
    {
        if(--refptr == 0)
            delete p;
    }

    operator bool() const { return p; }

private:
    T* p;
    Ptr_count refptr;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your question primarily boils down to: does this assignment call the destructor of the counter?

```
refptr = rhs.refptr;
```

The answer is no. Personally, I would be inclined to actually *not* wrap the counter code into a separate class and rather have it done in the `Ptr` class directly. Also, I think my canonical way to implement the assignment operator would take care of the correct behavior:

```
Ptr& Ptr::operator(Ptr other) {
    this->swap(other);
    return *this;
}
void Ptr::swap(Ptr& other) {
    std::swap(this->p, other.p);
    this->ptrcnt.swap(other.ptrcnt);
}
void Ptr_count::swap(Ptr_count& other) {
    std::swap(this->ptrcnt, other.ptrcnt);
}
```

That said, although a simple implementation of a reference counted pointer is a fun interview question, I strong recommend to *never* actually implement a reference counted pointer [unless you happen to also implement the rest of the standard C++ library] and just use `std::shared_ptr<T>`: apart from having worked out the nitty gritty details on how to manage the count, this class implements a couple of pretty cool features which go way beyond your simple reference counted pointer and many of these features actually happen to be needed in real code.